# interrupt program in debugger when c++ exception is thrown

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, gcc, breakpoints

How can I make `gdb` interrupt (like in breakpoint) the program at the point where an exception is thrown, and interrupt again on rethrows and beginnings of the relevant catch blocks?

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115428. FWIW, I answered this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`catch throw` and `catch catch`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_31.html).

Comment: Damn - you beat me by 8 seconds :)

Answer (score 3):

[Set a catchpoint.](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/gnu/gcc/gdb_6.html#SEC31)