# How to debug a program that is terminating in an unhandled exception?

Tags: c++, linux, exception

I am programming in C++ on Linux platform.

My program terminates with this (unhandled???) exception:

"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'long'"
Aborted

The code that is throwing the exception is inside try-catch block, then why should this happen??
The exception is thrown while returning from a function.

I am used to C programming and have very little experience in C++ (which is the main problem). I don't know how to debug this issue. I don't expect a solution but a direction/pointer for debugging this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you mention in a comment that you are using `catch(...)`, which should work, could you show us some code?

Comment: if you edit your question and add the code that exhibits this behaviour and we'll be more able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably catching the wrong exception type

use

```
catch(long)
```

or

```
catch(...)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can run your application under `gdb` (having built it with debug info using `-g`) and get it to break when an exception is thrown using the command:

```
(gdb) catch throw
```

This will take you to the origin of the exception.  Some more info is available in this question:

- [Run an application in GDB until an exception occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115428/run-an-application-in-gdb-until-an-exception-occurs)

Note that it is somewhat unusual to throw an ordinal type (such as a `long`). It may be in some temporary code, so grepping around might find it quickly enough.

Answer (score 5):

It there anywhere on the call-stack with a [exception specification](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr156.htm) or [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)? If there is then you might have this problem - you probably want to remove all of them.

If you are using gcc, then you can add this code first thing in `main()`:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    std::set_terminate(__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler);
#endif // ifdef __GNUC__
```

(More details at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt02ch06s02.html)
Which will give you a better traceback from such exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would recommend to set a breakpoint in the constructor of the thrown type -- but in this case ... I must admit to never have experienced that somebody has thrown a long like

```
throw 42;
```

That seems to me strange. Some debuggers might be able to catch an exception when it is thrown.

Is the called function yours?

Comment: throw 42 is cool - although it should not survive a code review. But still - it's cool.

Comment: That's the reason, the biggest computer ever build needs 7.5 million years to calculate it ;-) just because some ignorant code reviewers eliminated the line ...

Comment: 42 isn't a long, it's an int. :)

Comment: Right, I did not program in C++ for a long time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use set_terminate to break GDB

Example for `set_terminate()` is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/)

When it trigged - use bt command in GDB to see backtrace