# Linking binary compiled with "-g" with library without "-g"

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Will there be any issues if a binary compiled with gdb  symbols (-g) is linked with a library without gdb symbols?

I am debugging [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023492/backtrace-stopped-previous-frame-identical-to-this-frame-corrupt-stack-on) issue, and I am checking if the "-g" might be causing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linking libraries compiled with debug symbols and without debug symbols should not cause Segmentation fault. Debug symbols are used by the debugger only, so should not cause a Segementation fault.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "issues".

One obvious issue is that the shared library will be without debug symbols. Making it hard to debug ;) But afaik there are no mayor issues. This mix occurs all the time, some projects are released with debug symbols still attached. The reason for this is if you got the space on your harddrive, then why not keep it. While other project like the linux-kernel seperates the debug-symbols so they can be installed later if you realize you need them.