# Invalid cast in gdb (armv7)

Tags: c++, debugging, arm, gdb

I have a similar issue like in this question [GDB corrupted stack frame - How to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809810/gdb-corrupted-stack-frame-how-to-debug), like this:

```
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0x76bd6978 in fputs () from /lib/libc.so.6
 #1  0x0000b080 in getfunction1 ()
 #2  0x0000b080 in getfunction1 ()
 Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Chris Dodd wrote an answer to point the top of the stack to the program counter (PC). In a 32bit machine it shall be

```
(gdb) set $pc = *(void **)$esp
(gdb) set $esp = $esp + 4
```

However, after run the first line I got `invalid cast`:

```
(gdb) set $pc = *(void **)$esp
Invalid cast.
(gdb) set $esp = $esp + 4
Argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean.
```

Why do I get this messages? and how can I make a workaround to figure out where the crash occurs? I work on a armv7 machine with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

ESP does not exist in ARM. It's MSP (Main Stack Pointer) or PSP (Stack pointer).

[ARM Registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBIBGJ.html)

As ESP does not exists, that's why you get invalid cast. If you do the same command with another valid ARM register there is no error