# Is it possible for GDB to dump the code line by line which it executes?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I want `gdb` to dump the code it executes line by line. Just like `step` command as it shows the current line but I do not want do step through the entire code as it is too big.

So I want to automate it.

The reason I want to do this because my code behaves differently in two scenarios and I want to see where actually the diff arises so I plan to take dump for two different scenarios in two different file then take a diff.

I know it may not be the best way to debug something but trust me I have tried a lots of stuff to find the bug but no use and I think this can help me in a great way.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Probably looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/6964213/315052

Comment: got my answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812411/gdb-automatic-nexting/5813439#5813439

Answer (score 0):

With GDB you can set `breakpoints` that will allow you to follow step by step the code in a specific area of your programm.