# How to debug a std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime

I have a fairly large and complex program I am trying to debug right now. I keep getting a `St13runtime_error` and I have no idea what that means. I think its an `std::runtime_error`. Are there any general strategies I can employ here?

I have tried getting a stack trace and it just says `Unknown Function` for like half the trace which isn't very helpful even though I built in debug mode.

Comment: If that exception is not captured by any catch clause, your debugger will stop that process at where the exception being thrown, and you could get the stack trace and more debug information,

Comment: I know the debugger in Visual Studio that you can enable it to break on c++ exceptions thrown. I assume other debuggers have the same ability. Edit: This is for gdb: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115428/run-an-application-in-gdb-until-an-exception-occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115428/run-an-application-in-gdb-until-an-exception-occurs)

Comment: Oh the gdb one is especially helpful. Thank you both! I will do that.